# Res cannot be resolved with an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` in my android app. I'm using an `ImageView` as a button. When I press the button, the image should change. In my code, it says that `res cannot be resolved`. My code is below:

```
loginbtn.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    //here change images according to touch 
    loginbtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // 
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                v.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.compare_now_click));
                // res 
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
               v.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.));
                break;
            }
            }
            return true;


            return false;
        }
    });
```

On this line:

```
v.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.compare_now_click));
```

I'm getting the error `res cannot be resolved`. Why might this be happening?

Comment: what is `res` and where is it initialized?

Comment: @Raghunandan yap it is the problem.the code i extracted from web.there they didnt metioned it prpperly

Comment: looks like you have not initialized res properly. So show us that part of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.compare_now_click);
```

Otherwise, you have to get the resources from a context first, e.g. if you are in an `Activity`, use `Resources res = getResources();`

Moreover, your second image resource id is not complete: `R.drawable`